# what's the syntax of the new react version

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

guys, I want to print some components on the `App.js`  form the `index.js`

but I keep getting the module isn't found an error, and I noticed my syntax is outdated, can anyone pls tell me how to do it in the newer version, here is this code
and what do we write on the `App.js` to print them?

```
    var DATA = {    
    name: 'John Smith',
    imgURL: 'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/',
    hobbyList: ['coding', 'writing', 'skiing']
}
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Profile 
                    name={this.props.profileData.name} 
                    imgURL={this.props.profileData.imgURL}/>
                <Hobbies
                    hobbyList={this.props.profileData.hobbyList} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: "*the moudle isn't found error*"? Please post the exact error message that you are getting

Comment: Are you exporting the `App`? Are you then importing it in `index.js`?

Comment: I'm trying to import index.js into App.jx to just print somthing out on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to import the profile and hobbies components as well once you build those.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const DATA = {    
    name: 'John Smith',
    imgURL: 'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/',
    hobbyList: ['coding', 'writing', 'skiing']
}
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const { profileData: { name, imgURL, hobbyList } } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <Profile 
                    name={name} 
                    imgURL={imgURL}/>
                <Hobbies
                    hobbyList={hobbyList} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App profileData={DATA} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Error :  Duplicate declaration "Profile"

  39 | var App2 = require('create-react-class');
  40 | 
> 41 | var Profile = App2({
     |     ^
  42 |     render: function(){
  43 |         return (
  44 |             <div>

Comment: You don't need to require create-react-class. Are you following a tutorial or blog post?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to do what this guys is doing https://medium.com/learning-new-stuff/building-your-first-react-js-app-d53b0c98dc

Comment: That tutorial is out of date now. I would suggest another resource. This is a good starter course: https://egghead.io/courses/the-beginner-s-guide-to-react

Here is the updated code for the tutorial: https://scrimba.com/p/playlist-1/cast-268

Comment: thank you so much sir, I copied all his code, and placed into index.js and i got this error : Duplicate declaration "Profile"

  21 | }
  22 | 
> 23 | class Profile extends React.Component {
     |       ^
  24 |   render() {
  25 |     return (
  26 |       <div>

Comment: I just want to learn how it works, and step by step I can learn it, but it seems so hard

Comment: thank you so much sir :) and I heard React is the way to go now, i used to program using PHP, and Javascript, this is kinda new to me

Comment: I'm on twitter _birdwell if you have any more questions or need help finding tutorials or courses. I taught myself React awhile back and don't mind helping!

Comment: I really appreciate it, I'll look u up now

Comment: do u know man how to render the Data from the App, cause the guy code is manually entering the element, I need to render an obejct Data from the Main in his code